# How to call a stored procedure in Entity Framework in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am new to entity framework and I want to know how to call the SP in Business layer using Entity Framework.

Comment: Read [this excellent MSDN article on the topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) - should explain most of your questions

Comment: I am using schema first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to add the stored procedure by selecting the Add/Edit SPs wizard.

Then later you have to add a function import for it.

In the same wizard you have add the new complex type which is the result set of the stored procedure.

Suppose the complex type is `SP_ComplexType` and function import name `SP_Func`, here is how you can use it.

```
var SP_ComplexType  = entity.SP_Func.ToList();
```